# Passing jquery variable from one php page to another php page using jquery and ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
First PHP Page and Jquery :
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function get_ver() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var ver = $("#OSVER option:selected" ).text();
                alert (ver);
          $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: 'create_policy.php',
                data: { 'OSVER'  : ver }
         });

         });
}
</script>
<?php

 <b><a href='index.php?xtype=create_policy&pol_id=$pol_id&pol_type=$pol_type'  class='texthidevisi' onClick='get_ver()' >Edit |</a></b>


Second PHP Page : 
<?php
$ver=$_POST['OSVER'];
echo "Version is $ver";
?>
```

In the first php  page I am calling jquery function get_ver() which will get the values from drop down box. I am able to get the value selected in the jquery variable "ver", but I am not able to get it second php page.

Comment: use success function in ajax to get second page respone.

$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: 'create_policy.php',
                data: { 'OSVER'  : ver },
                success : function(response){ alert(response) }
         });

Comment: What value u get in alert ?

Comment: @ jQuery - Still not getting anything

Comment: @ jQuery.PHP.Magento.com - Im getting decimal values which is intended and correct one.

Comment: If you try http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ like $.post( "create_policy.php", { OSVER: ver })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); does this work?
  });

Comment: @trainoasis - Nope , its not working...

Comment: Is 2nd php page on same folder ? Execute localhost/YourFolder/create_policy.php   Directly in URL what do u get ?  What console error you get ?

Comment: Yes its in the same folder... Im getting the print message "Version is    " with the $ver as null..So, only variable value is not passing.

Comment: Try with below code 
<?php
$ver=$_POST['OSVER'];
echo "Version is ".$ver;
die();
?>

Comment: Still Not working...